# Mouse dragging does not work with Alps touchpad and stick

Tags: touchpad, dell, synaptics, trackpoint, alps

I have a Dell Latitude E7470 in which a combined touchpad/stick Alps device does the mousing work.  Since kernel 4.9 (from mainline kernel PPA) this is supported and xinput lists it as:

```
shell> xinput list | grep Alps
↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

After some twiddling I managed to make the stick usable, turned off edge-scrolling which would basically scroll in the whole right half of the touch pad. But one thing still does not work:

Whenever I use the left mouse button of the stick (the one below the space-bar), I can not drag anything by moving the pointer with the touchpad.  Every other combination of mouse button and pointing device (even with two additional devices connected via USB) works, as far as I can see.  But this particular combination does not.  And I use it a lot.

It did work with older kernels, but there the Alps device was not detected as a touchpad at all.

Any pointers how to debug this or what settings to try out are highly appreciated.  I know about `xev` but I did not find its output usable for this situation.  I tried `xinput --test-xi2` but it didn't make a lot of sense to me.  I know how to call `xinput` to adjust some settings.

Thanks!

Comment: In the meantime, I gathered more information.  But still without a solution. Using the instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection/evtest I created logs of the events of both parts of the Alps DualPoint device.  This shows that when pressing and holding the left mouse button of the stick and then moving the pointer on the touchpad, a button release event is fired for the first button press. Works the other way round, too: press&hold left button of touchpad and then move pointer with the stick.  Dragging does not work that way, neither.

Comment: Created a Kernel bug at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=191741

Answer (score 1):

The kernel bug was resolved in 4.10.0-rc3. Right now, I am not 4.10.0-rc5 and it works well.